# Is there a way to use idle computing power in my second laptop to speed up my main laptop?

Tags: networking, grid, memory

I'm not sure if this question makes sense, but I'm going to try:

My second laptop is more powerful than the one I use at home (more RAM etc). I'd like to continue using my slower laptop as my main laptop (considering the second one is from work), so is there a way I could somehow tap into the more powerful resources my second laptop has to offer?

Comment: Unless you want to write your own custom OS and parallelize all your software to take advantage of this new oS, then no... at most you could pop up a remote desktop from the fast machine to the slow one, but you can't "fuse" two machines into a single one.

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking, no. In order to combine processing resources like that, the application needs to be "in on it" - it needs to be specifically designed for what you're doing here. OS-level multiprocessing generally requires a fast shared memory bus, which is not possible to achieve with two random consumer-level PCs.